# why change ubuntu16.04 timezone in docker is invalid

Tags: ubuntu, docker, timezone, dockerfile, tzdata

I use command `apt-get install -y tzdata && echo Asia/Shanghai > /etc/timezone && dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata` to change timezone to UTC+8，but it doesn't work。My Dockerfile as follows:

```
FROM ubuntu:xenial
MAINTAINER Leon.Gan
RUN mv /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.bak \
  && echo "deb http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu/ xenial main" >/etc/apt/sources.list \
  && echo "deb-src http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu/ xenial main" >>/etc/apt/sources.list \
  && echo "deb http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main" >>/etc/apt/sources.list \
  && echo "deb-src http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main" >>/etc/apt/sources.list \
  && echo "deb http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe" >>/etc/apt/sources.list \
  && echo "deb-src http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe" >>/etc/apt/sources.list \
  && echo "deb http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe" >>/etc/apt/sources.list \
  && echo "deb-src http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe" >>/etc/apt/sources.list \
  && echo "deb http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main" >>/etc/apt/sources.list \
  && echo "deb-src http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main" >>/etc/apt/sources.list \
  && echo "deb http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security universe" >>/etc/apt/sources.list \
  && echo "deb-src http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security universe" >>/etc/apt/sources.list \
  && apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y locales \
  && locale-gen zh_CN.UTF-8 \
  && apt-get install -y tzdata \
  && echo Asia/Shanghai > /etc/timezone \
  && dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV LC_ALL "zh_CN.UTF-8"
ENV LANG "zh_CN.UTF-8"

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

After build image, I enter the container, run command `cat /etc/timezone`，the content is still Etc/UTC. It means my command `echo Asia/Shanghai > /etc/timezone` in Dockerfile is not work. So, plz teach me how to change the timezone correctly, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata` does something wrong.

I recommend to either set `ENV TZ=Asia/Shanghai` and/or to run

```
ln -s -f /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Shanghai /etc/localtime
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
ENV TZ=Asia/Singapore
```

in your dockerfile. It is setiing global environment timezone to proprer one.

Comment: `Europe/Singapore` is not a [valid time zone identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).